# URL structure not changing on godaddy

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

My URL : `http://example.com/index.php?L=F/12345678`

This is what i tried.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ index.php?L=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This is what i expect: `http://example.com/F/12345678` but dosent work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /index\.php\?L=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%2\? [R,L]

#Internal rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?L=$1 [L]
```

It should change `http://example.com/index.php?L=F/12345678` to `http://example.com/F/12345678`

Comment: You need to add a `<base href="http://example.com/`> into the head tag. Or add a `/` before all image links. Also can you edit your comment so it's not in all caps?

Comment: i cant edit my comment because i edited once. caps lock was on when i write the comment :D.  thanks for your help now im trying to add `base href`. thanks

Comment: what does this line mean `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /index\.php\?L=(.*)\ HTTP` ?

Comment: It basically says if the url contains `index.php` and had the parameter `?L=` then it will continue with rewrite and add anything after the `?L=` to `http://example.com`

Comment: hello how to change also the url struture of this: `posts.php?L=V/12345678` using the same code. thanks

Comment: your code changed the `index.php` but i want also the change this `posts.php?L=V/12345678`

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?L=$1 [L]
```

Comment: "doesnt work" is not the least bit helpful in determining why. You might want to elaborate on that if you really want someone's help.

Comment: thanks for your help. the url remain the same and nothing changed.